# Re-placed GPS with Fake GPS Free (Honor 6 H60-L04)

Tags: gps

I used /system/app mover ★ ROOT ★(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.systemappmover&hl=en) to replace my GPS. But it didnt work as i want it to, so i tried to remove it but it didnt work. It keeps giving me error notes saying not mountable and others. i even adding other GPS apps to replace it but couldnt.
I Hard Reset the phone but its still there.. Please Help.

Comment: Welcome to Android.SE! We hope you'll like the place and decide to stay. I don't know the answer to your question. Try to get enough upvotes for your question so that it will get tweeted out on the site's Twitter feed. Please [edit] it for spelling and grammar, and also to tell us: 1. What version of Android are you using? 2. What original GPS app did you try to replace? 3. Could you please copy and paste the exact error messages into your question?